# Xamarin Sqlite query with sum()

Tags: database, sqlite, xamarin, sum

i got a sqlite db with some values, one of it is called "NWPrice". i want to Sum() the price, so i can put it into a string(label) later on. its like in a normal online shop, you got some stuff with a price and its added to "summe" in the end. (dont worry, its not a real shop, was just an exampel). so here is the code i got( i tried it in 2 ways, so thats why there are "summe" and "z"):

```
            var summe = await _connection.QueryAsync<Bestellung>("SELECT SUM(NWPrice) FROM Bestellung"); 
            var z = summe.ToList().FirstOrDefault();

            SummeEinkauf.Text = summe.ToString();
            Summenlabel.Text = z.ToString();
```

and the outcome for z its writing "Projektname.PackegeName" and for summe its writing "system.collections.generic.list´1[projektname.models.classname]"

can you help me :D?

by the way(found this allready here):

```
 var ent = conn.Table<Transaction>().Where(t => t.price > 0);
 entLabel.Text = (ent.Sum(t => t.price)).ToString();
```

this one doesnt work, it says it cant convert a string to a bool in the "where-
clinches"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally here´s an answer:

```
var ent = await _connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>("SELECT SUM(NWPreis) FROM BESTELLUNG");
SummeEinkauf.Text = ent.ToString();
```

if there s anybody who can tell me (exactly for my case) how i can write the answer in this format "0.00" and not (like it is now) in thie "0" or this "0.0" it would be grat. but the most is done :)